# How to convert GCI DirectoryName to string for .Substring()

Tags: string, powershell, type-conversion, get-childitem

Trying to output just the immediate parent folder from this as the full path is too big. The ultimate goal is to output duplicate files from different folders ordered by modify date.

I think I need to cast the `gci DirectoryName` output as a string so I can `.Substring($LenRootPath)` as per below:

I've tried `-Expand`, but it can't convert `System.Object` to `System.String`. I also tried `[string[]]`, which is ignored, and 
tried `.Substring($rootPath.Length)`, but still get a `System.Object`.

Cast `gci directoryname` as string?

```cs
$rootPath = "c:\test" 
$array = @(Join-Path $rootPath "\1111\", 
           Join-Path $rootPath "\2222\", 
           Join-Path $rootPath "\3333\")

Get-ChildItem -Path $array -Filter "*.doc" -Recurse |
  where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
  Select-Object DirectoryName, Name, LastWriteTime | 
  Sort-Object Name, LastWriteTime -Desc |
  Format-Table @{
    Name="LastWriteTime";
    Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")}
  }, DirectoryName -GroupBy Name
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is in the definition of `$array`. You need to add brackets around each so that the cmdlet executes before it's interpreted as a string in the array. E.g:

```
$array = @((join-path $rootPath "\1111\"), 
           (join-path $rootPath "\2222\"), 
           (join-path $rootPath "\3333\"))
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I replaced the $array with $rootPath, a single string, in the gci call - it doesn't change a thing...?

Comment: Substituting `$array` for `$rootPath` works for me, so I don't think there's anything else wrong with your code. Does your directory definitely contain *.doc files? Also what PowerShell version are you using? (enter `$psversiontable` at the console)